# GIFEncoder V2.05: 0 Source is not a GIF image

Tags: php, image-processing

i am using `gifencoder` class but when i upload images it gives error

> GIFEncoder V2.05: 0 Source is not a GIF image

below is the code

```
if (isset($_POST['speed'])) {
header('Content-type: image/gif');
if (isset($_POST['download'])) {
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="animated.gif"');
}

include('GIFEncoder.class.php');

function frame($image) {
    ob_start();
    imagegif($image);
    global $frames, $framed;
    $frames[] = ob_get_contents();
    $framed[] = $_POST['speed'];
    ob_end_clean();
}

$cnt = count($_FILES);

for ($key = 1; $key <= $cnt; $key++) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["images" . $key]["tmp_name"];
    $im = imagecreatefrompng(file_get_contents($tmp_name));
    $resized = imagecreatetruecolor($_POST['width'], $_POST['height']);
    imagecopyresized($resized, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, $_POST['width'], $_POST['height'], imagesx($im), imagesy($im));
    frame($resized);
}
$gif = new GIFEncoder($frames, $framed, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 'bin');
echo $gif->GetAnimation();
}
```

I have tried to chnage mode from 'url' to 'bin' but its not working.

Comment: an example would be a good start point ... input image output gif image and source code. Have you tried to decode the GIF? see what is wrong with it like missing header, wrong resolution, missing clear codes etc ... see [decoding GIF87a](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29924219/2521214) especially the 3MF sublink !!!

Comment: you should also add the resulting image file here so we can see what is wrong with it...