# How to find where does Image Block start in GIF images?

Tags: image, gif, decoding, file-format

Information source - http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/formats/gif.html#header

In **GIF** images the actual image size (width, height) is stored in Image Block. To my best understanding **Image Block** is the very first block included in header.
Before the actual blocks begin, there is a memory allocation called **Global Color Table**(0..255 x 3 bytes)(from now-on **GCT**). If I can know the byte count reserved for **GCT** I can extract bytes 5-9 from **Image Block** and have the actual image size.

**Question:**
How can I know/learn what is the size of the **GCT**?

**OR**

Where does **GCT** end?

**OR**

Where does **Image Block** begin?

**OR**

Where does **Image Block** end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need for gif enc/dec you will find here [3MF Project GIF](http://www.matthewflickinger.com/lab/whatsinagif/lzw_image_data.asp)

1. **GCT**

   this block is optional and not always present in a **GIF** file. Size is determined by number of colors and bit wide from **GIF** header. I decode/load it like this:

   ```cpp
   struct _hdr
       {
       // Header
       BYTE Signature[3];      /* Header Signature (always "GIF") */
       BYTE Version[3];        /* GIF format version("87a" or "89a") */
       // Logical Screen Descriptor
       WORD xs;
       WORD ys;
       BYTE Packed;            /* Screen and Color Map Information */
       BYTE BackgroundColor;   /* Background Color Index */
       BYTE AspectRatio;       /* Pixel Aspect Ratio */
       } hdr;

   gcolor_bits= (hdr.Packed    &7)+1;  // global pallete
   scolor_bits=((hdr.Packed>>4)&7)+1;  // screen
   _gcolor_sorted =hdr.Packed&8;
   _gcolor_table  =hdr.Packed&128;
   scolors=1<<scolor_bits;
   gcolors=1<<gcolor_bits;
   ```

   - if `_gcolor_table` is true then **GCT** is present
   - **GCT** size is `3*gcolors` [Bytes] stored in order `R,G,B`
2. **Start of Image**

   This one is a bit tricky because **GIF89a** files may contain many optional blocks. You need to do a decoding loop detecting type of block and decoding/skipping it according its purpose. I do it like this:

   ```cpp
   struct _gfxext
       {
       BYTE Introducer;        /* Extension Introducer (always 21h) */
       BYTE Label;             /* Graphic Control Label (always F9h) */
       BYTE BlockSize;         /* Size of remaining fields (always 04h) */
       BYTE Packed;            /* Method of graphics disposal to use */
       WORD DelayTime;         /* Hundredths of seconds to wait    */
       BYTE ColorIndex;        /* Transparent Color Index */
       BYTE Terminator;        /* Block Terminator (always 0) */
       } gfx;

   struct _txtext
       {
       BYTE Introducer;        /* Extension Introducer (always 21h) */
       BYTE Label;             /* Extension Label (always 01h) */
       BYTE BlockSize;         /* Size of Extension Block (always 0Ch) */
       WORD TextGridLeft;      /* X position of text grid in pixels */
       WORD TextGridTop;       /* Y position of text grid in pixels */
       WORD TextGridWidth;     /* Width of the text grid in pixels */
       WORD TextGridHeight;    /* Height of the text grid in pixels */
       BYTE CellWidth;         /* Width of a grid cell in pixels */
       BYTE CellHeight;        /* Height of a grid cell in pixels */
       BYTE TextFgColorIndex;  /* Text foreground color index value */
       BYTE TextBgColorIndex;  /* Text background color index value */
   //      BYTE *PlainTextData;    /* The Plain Text data */
   //      BYTE Terminator;        /* Block Terminator (always 0) */
       };

   struct _remext
       {
       BYTE Introducer;        /* Extension Introducer (always 21h) */
       BYTE Label;             /* Comment Label (always FEh) */
   //      BYTE *CommentData;      /* Pointer to Comment Data sub-blocks */
   //      BYTE Terminator;        /* Block Terminator (always 0) */
       };

   struct _appext
       {
       BYTE Introducer;        /* Extension Introducer (always 21h) */
       BYTE Label;             /* Extension Label (always FFh) */
       BYTE BlockSize;         /* Size of Extension Block (always 0Bh) */
       CHAR Identifier[8];     /* Application Identifier */
       BYTE AuthentCode[3];    /* Application Authentication Code */
   //      BYTE *ApplicationData;  /* Point to Application Data sub-blocks */
   //      BYTE Terminator;        /* Block Terminator (always 0) */
       };
   // handle 89a extensions blocks
   _gfxext gfxext; gfxext.Introducer=0;
   _txtext txtext; txtext.Introducer=0;
   _remext remext; remext.Introducer=0;
   _appext appext; appext.Introducer=0;

   if((hdr.Version[0]=='8')
    &&(hdr.Version[1]=='9')
    &&(hdr.Version[2]=='a')) _89a=true; else _89a=false;

   if (_89a)
    for (;!f.eof;)
       {
       f.peek((BYTE*)&dw,2);
            if (dw==0xF921) { f.read((BYTE*)&gfxext,sizeof(_gfxext)); }
       else if (dw==0x0121) { f.read((BYTE*)&txtext,sizeof(_txtext)); for (;!f.eof;) { f.read(&db,1); if (!db) break; f.read(dat,DWORD(db)); } }
       else if (dw==0xFE21) { f.read((BYTE*)&remext,sizeof(_remext)); for (;!f.eof;) { f.read(&db,1); if (!db) break; f.read(dat,DWORD(db)); } }
       else if (dw==0xFF21) { f.read((BYTE*)&appext,sizeof(_appext)); for (;!f.eof;) { f.read(&db,1); if (!db) break; f.read(dat,DWORD(db)); } }
       else if ((dw&0x00FF)==0x0021) return; // corrupted file
       else break;                           // no extension found
       }
   ```

   - `db` is BYTE variable
   - `dw` is WORD variable
   - `f` is my file cache class the members are self explanatory I hope anyway:
   - `f.read(&data,size)` read `size` BYTES into `data`
   - `f.peek(&data,size)` do the same but do not update position in file
   - `f.eof` indicates end of file reached

   this has to be done for each frame after all this image header starts.
3. **End of Image**

   Image block ends with terminator. All the chunks of image start with `BYTE` count. If it is `zero` it is a terminator block. Usually after the image there are few `BYTES` not used by **LZW** data so after you fill the whole image area skip all blocks until hit the zero sized block and then stop that is image end. If `BYTE` after this is `0x3B` hex you reached the end of **GIF** file

**[notes]**

Do not forget to encapsulate struct by `#pragma pack(1)` and `#pragma pack()` or manually set **align** to `1 BYTE`. Beware problems with signed data types (**LZW** data is unsigned) so overtype where you can to avoid problems or use just unsigned variables (with enough bit-width) for decoding