# Pseudocode: How to decode a PNG file from bits and bytes?

Tags: image, algorithm, bitmap, png, pseudocode

I've been trying to figure this out by reverse engineering a .png file I created in GIMP. It's 4x4 pixels. My goal is to decode the raw pixels out of the file with the intent of reversing this to encode.

Here is a full hex dump of the file:

```
89504E47 0D0A1A0A 0000000D 49484452 00000004 00000004  
08020000 00269309 29000000 3F494441 54081D01 3400CBFF  
01CC96B1 134FE120 C0CECDF1 5101FFA5 60000000 000000E0  
403201DF E59286DF 6D000000 00000004 EDB11F00 2E007A21  
93EDB11F 3063136F 4733525A 00000000 49454E44 AE426082
```

According to the [spec](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html), we start with the PNG signature which is the first 8 bytes.

> 89504E47 0D0A1A0A

We then have repeating "chunk" structures, this file has 3 "chunks", the header (IHDR), the image data (IDAT) and then the end "chunk" (IEND).

Each chunk is arranged into: the first 4 bytes for the length of the chunk data, the next 4 bytes for the type of data, then n-bytes for the actual data and then 4 bytes for the cyclic redundancy check (CRC) of the type of data and actual data sections.

Following this through...

> 0000000D

Is the chunk's data length (13 bytes).

> 49484452

Is the chunk's type (IHDR).

> 00000004 00000004 08020000 00

Is the chunk's data (4 bytes width, height; 1 byte bit depth, colour type, compression method, filter method, interlace method).

> 269309 29

Is the CRC of the data and type (managed to get the code to work this out from [here](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-CRCAppendix.html).

> 000000 3F

Is the next chunk's data length (63 bytes).

> 494441 54

Is the chunk's type (IDAT).

> 081D01 3400CBFF 01CC96B1 134FE120 C0CECDF1 5101FFA5 60000000 000000E0 403201DF E59286DF 6D000000 00000004 EDB11F00 2E007A21 93EDB11F 3063136F

Is the chunk's actual data (the image data compressed and filtered).

So my actual question is how do I decode this last section into raw pixels?

According to the [spec](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html#C.IDAT), I must first decompress the data (INFLATE?) and then unfilter it (??) to be left with scanlines of pixels (my goal).

**If this could be explained in pseudocode that would be amazing! Otherwise I'm familiar with Swift and less so with C...**

Comment: I understand that you want to do this strictly for the challenge, because otherwise you should use a pre-existing library.

Comment: Are you sure you want to implement the zlib components, or is it OK for you to use libraries for decompression and/or filtering? Pseudocode for zlib is not small, partly because there are variants to consider.

Comment: I would prefer to implement zlib; calling on a library doesn't really teach me anything. If not pseudocode perhaps, just broken down into simpler steps that I can research myself?

Comment: If I where you I would start with [GIF ... as it is well documented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32369298/2521214) with examples (see the 3MF link in there) and contains very similar compression algo. When done then move to png. Another possibility is to use zlib and when working replace zlib calls one by one by your own code. Sadly did not do the PNG decoder/encoder my self (I use pngDelphi) so can not help more in detail , however I did do [PCX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37340970/2521214),GIF,DDS,SGI,SVG,EMF,WMF and more  decoders/encoders in the past (as I needed them)

Comment: Anyway you should add some code and where exactly you are stuck so this interesting question does not get closed as too broad or off topic ....

Answer (score 4):

This book explains the process of decoding for programmers:

[https://www.amazon.com/Compressed-Image-File-Formats-JPEG/dp/0201604434](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201604434)

The entire process is way to complicated to fit within the space of a SO answer. PNG uses two different methods of compression: LZ and Huffman encoding.

Comment: The book explains step-by-step how to do PNG decoding.

Answer (score 2):

I think `pngcheck` will help you considerably:

```
pngcheck -vv result.png
```

**Sample Output**

```
File: result.png (334985 bytes)
  chunk IHDR at offset 0x0000c, length 13
    600 x 450 image, 24-bit RGB, non-interlaced
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x00025, length 65536
    zlib: deflated, 32K window, default compression
    row filters (0 none, 1 sub, 2 up, 3 avg, 4 paeth):
      1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
      1 4 4 1 4 1 4 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
      1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 4 4 1 4 1 1 4
      4 4 4 4 4 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 (96 out of 450)
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x10031, length 65536
    row filters (0 none, 1 sub, 2 up, 3 avg, 4 paeth):
      1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1
      4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
      4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 4 4
      4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 4 4 4 (188 out of 450)
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x2003d, length 65536
    row filters (0 none, 1 sub, 2 up, 3 avg, 4 paeth):
      4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
      4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
      4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
      4 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 (273 out of 450)
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x30049, length 65536
    row filters (0 none, 1 sub, 2 up, 3 avg, 4 paeth):
      4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 2 4 4 4 4 4 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
      4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
      4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 4 4 4
      4 4 4 4 1 4 4 4 (356 out of 450)
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x40055, length 65536
    row filters (0 none, 1 sub, 2 up, 3 avg, 4 paeth):
      4 4 4 4 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
      4 4 4 1 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 4 4 1 4 4 1 1 1 4 4 4
      4 4 1 1 1 4 1 4 4 4 1 4 1 4 4 4 1 4 1 4 4 4 4 4 4
      4 1 1 4 1 4 4 1 4 1 (441 out of 450)
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x50061, length 7188
    row filters (0 none, 1 sub, 2 up, 3 avg, 4 paeth):
      4 1 1 4 4 4 4 1 4 (450 out of 450)
  chunk IEND at offset 0x51c81, length 0
No errors detected in result.png (8 chunks, 58.6% compression).
```

Comment: `File: understand.png (120 bytes)
  chunk IHDR at offset 0x0000c, length 13
    4 x 4 image, 24-bit RGB, non-interlaced
  chunk IDAT at offset 0x00025, length 63
    zlib: deflated, 256-byte window, superfast compression
    row filters (0 none, 1 sub, 2 up, 3 avg, 4 paeth):
      1 1 1 4 (4 out of 4)
  chunk IEND at offset 0x00070, length 0
No errors detected in understand.png (3 chunks, -150.0% compression).`

Answer (score 2):

Your question is way too broad for pseudocode -- or at least, actionable pseudocode - if we go high-level enough, you already know the basics: 1. uncompress, 2. unfilter, 3. profit.

Since you state in comments that you want to do everything yourself, I propose that you start by implementing the default decompression algorithm, ZLIB CM=8 "deflate", which is well-described in https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt among others.