# Gif Image is not animating in firefox

Tags: html, firefox, firefox-addon, animated-gif

I am facing very strange problem with Firefox and GIF image. **I have two-three GIF Image in a web page all the GIF animating except one**

A GIF image which is not animating in Firefox (Shows Last Frame), does animation in all other browsers like Chrome, Safari , IE. I have latest or nearly latest browser installed.

Please help me to resolve this issue. can that be a problem of Animation Engine like stuff?

Comment: The gif may be set to play once, and it already played once on another page. try hitting ctrl+f5 to hard refresh.

Comment: i have checked **"animation_mode"** its set to **"normal"**. but my problem with only one image. Also cleared everything from browser even disabled all the extensions.

Comment: Ctrl + F5 didnt fix it?

Comment: Without code (e.g. example GIF), this question may be off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working the way I want?**") must include: A) the desired behavior; B) a specific problem or error *and* C) **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** all ***in the question itself***. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Might be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867789/animated-gif-only-loops-once-in-chrome-and-firefox