# Looping Gif won't work on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops, gif, preloader

I'm having an awful time trying to get something working for a client. 
Basically, I've created an animated looping gif which he wanted for his Wordpress website, as a preloader thing. Now, I had absolutely no success with the preloader - I tried inserting the gif in, but the preloader literally featured for three seconds and then disappeared. The gif was too small to even be seen.

So I thought maybe I could create a sort of splash page, where a user could see the animated gif, and there could be a Welcome To ..... and a button to click into the website. BUT... I can't get the animated gif to play more than once... which is definitely not what the client wants. I'm exhausted - I've been through the various forums and tried the solutions on offer (checked that the gif hadn't been resized in Wordpress, made sure I had exported the gif from Photoshop with the looping option on).

It's nearly Christmas, and you guys would make my wish come true if you could help me solve this! :)

If you want to check out the link, it's down below:

http://www.benwinters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Snowflake-1.gif

Thank you!

Comment: You need to share your code for how you're adding this to the site. As it has been written, this question is off-topic for StackOverflow...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animated gif only loops once in Chrome and Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867789/animated-gif-only-loops-once-in-chrome-and-firefox)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm pretty new to this site. I've simply uploaded the gif and placed it into the page using html:

<img src="http://www.benwinters.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Snowflake-1.gif" alt="" width="800" height="450" />

I did try add the code that was suggested in the Animated gif only loops once, but with no success.

Comment: @Vogelina possibly the same issue as this [Animated gif only loops once in Chrome and Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38082881/2521214) I just answered. [Edit] ow it is already linked sorry but take a look there anyway if the solution works for you too

Answer (score 0):

loop is not a standard attribute, as far as I know. Instead of the loop attribute, you can [modify the gif file to repeat infinitely](https://superuser.com/questions/159212/how-do-i-make-an-existing-animated-gif-loop-repeatedly). You can do that in [Photoshop](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1026440?start=0&tstart=0) as well, if it is more handy to you.