# Gif only looping once

Tags: gif

This gif normally loops infinitely, but when I uploaded this gif to my wordpress site (or anywhere online) it only loops once.

```
<img loop=infinite class="wp-image-161 size-full" src="http://i2.wp.com/yobd.digital/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/merge-lines.gif" alt="Merging Lines with a macro!">
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean loop infinity? Opening where?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Animated gif only loops once in Chrome and Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867789/animated-gif-only-loops-once-in-chrome-and-firefox)

Comment: @PhiterFernandes if you download the image here: http://yobd.digital/img/merge-lines.gif you will see it loops infinitely

Comment: @PhiterFernandes sorry about that. I dont know why not. When I downloaded it from there and opened it in the default photo viewer on window 10 it did loop infinitely

Comment: It's looping only on windows apps. It should loop on browsers. That's odd

Comment: thats what I thought :)

Comment: @yobddigi found solution see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add application extension to force looping:

```
0x21,0xFF,0x0B,"NETSCAPE","2.0",0x03,0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00
```

Place it anywhere after GIF header and before first image header

for more info see [Animated gif only loops once in Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38082881/2521214)

After I done it to your GIF it loops:

[image: fixed]

Comment: I'm away at the moment will try this when I get home. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "LOOP=INFINITE"

Comment: As in the answer on the question this one is a duplicate of.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes i have updated my question adding this code as I did already try that and it didn't work. This is not the correct answer for my question.

Comment: Perhaps you have added too much timing in the last frame.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes No if you download the image and view it locally it will loop properly

Comment: Can you post the psd file somewhere? @YobdDigital