# Play Gif image in HTML with infinite loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried displaying a gif animated image inside my HTML code like

```
<img src="preview.gif" loop=infinite />
```

With or without the loop tag , it always plays once only.

Any help to make it loop continuously?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867789/animated-gif-only-loops-once-in-chrome-and-firefox

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Looping is encoded into the GIF itself, not the `img` tag. Open the GIF in an image editor and change the mode to loop, or use a different GIF. The `loop` attribute is an invalid, deprecated attribute only meant to work when the `src` is a video.

Comment: `imagemagic` did the job for me simply converting the gif into a loopable version. I followed https://superuser.com/a/888500/250469.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned it is encoded into the GIF but you can change it with tools like photoshop for this:

- Open your file in Photoshop
- Go to File and click Save For Web
- At the very bottom of the save dialog, you will see the Animation section, which should no longer be greyed out
- Choose forever and save it.

Comment: You can perform a similar process using GIMP, and it's free!

Answer (score 0):

The infinite attribute has no effect on the image. You have to store the infinite on the gif itself in case you generate it on the backend.