# How to restart an animated gif when the image tag is within a div with a *ngIf?

Tags: html, angular

I have an issue with an animated gif that I want to be restarted each time a condition is true.

```
 <div *ngIf="myCondition" class="main-container">
    <div class="photo-display">
       <img id="my-gif" class="animation-pr" src="./assets/images/animation-pr.gif"/>
   </div>
 ...
 </div>
```

Each time *myCondition* is true, I would like that my animated gif is restarted from the beginning of the sequence but it is not.
I tried different tricks found on this forum like setting the *src=""* before setting the path back, but when I tried to call *getElementById('my-gif')*, it returns null even when **myCondition* === true*. I think these tricks work when the *img* tag is always there.
Thanks for your help.

Note: I would like to keep the **ngIf* because it is used in different places in the HTML page.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498474/play-gif-image-in-html-with-infinite-loop